# Is it possible to blend overlapping layers with seamless transition using G'IMC filter or something else with Krita?

Tags: automation, filter, krita

Lets say I have a texture that I want to make tillable/seamless:

[image]

What I normally do is cut it in half, move the halves to opposite sides, overlap them a fair bit so that the repeating but irregular pattern somewhat matches a few times. It leaves a seam:

[image]

But then I can use Photoshop’s Edit → Auto Blend Layers function in “Panorama” mode and it finds a path that blends the layers in a visually seamless way:

[image]

The problem is - I hate Photoshop with pure hatred and would like to use Krita instead.

G’MIC has so many different filters (I am not familiar with all of them) and I am wondering maybe there is something similar there that could be used to replicate some sort of similar functionality. Is there?

I do understand I can paint it manually, but that takes a lot more time. Or I could blend layers with gradient changing opacity, but that doesn’t work at all with many patterns.

*What I have already tried:*

I tried GIMP's Filter -> Map -> Tile Seamless, but is seems to beo pacity based so it produces washed out results.

I am experimenting in Krita with G'MIC's Array & Tiles - > Make Seamless [Patch-Based] and it seems to work a lot better than GIMP's Tile Seamless, but it's not as good as Photoshop's panoramic blend, so I am still looking for other possibly better solutions.

Comment: I do keep GIMP installed so it would work too, but that is actually opacity based - it produces washed out result so that's no good. I am currently experimenting with G'MIC's  Array & Tiles - > Make Seamless [Patch-Based] and it seems to work a lot better. Not as good as Photoshop's panoramic blend still. but it's a bit faster, I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Krita, but GIMP has a *Layer > Tranform > Offset* function.  You can basically enable it, then click and drag the image using the Move Tool to see the seams.

An example. You can see me offsetting the image so the seams are shown like a cross in the middle of the image.

[image]

From here, you could now use the Clone Stamp tool to paint over the seams. Use a soft edged brush when cloning so you don't get any hard edges.

For example

[image]

Here's the finished seamless tile.

[image]

Comment: Like I said, painting it manually is usually too time consuming when compared to the way in Photoshop. I am wondering if there is a more automatic way. It seems the answer may turn out  to be no. G'MIC's Make Seamless [Patch-Based]  produces results of similar quality automatically. It's available for GIMP as well.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys It's not really that time consuming. You only have to select a few clone sources for the clone tool, and then you can more or less paint in continous strokes. Painting the above took me about 30 seconds. Automatic methods to do this would likely have to analyse the image in some way to get a good result. Maybe some AI software could do it.

Comment: No need for other software G'MIC filter in Krita and GIMP does it automatically. It is a good solution in general, but with Photoshop, the result is completely sharp so still a little bit better. It's harder to see how it's better on this fabric example, maybe I should have thought it through better, and posted some wood veneer texture. On wood textures Photoshop's panorama merging works way better and difference can be seen.

Comment: Also this example is sort of "zoomed in". Larger areas of fabrics are considerably more time consuming to paint by hand. Maybe I should look for functionality dedicated to joining panoramas.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys GIMP's automatic seamless tile function doesn't work so well with repeating patterns - it's really better for more random patterns.   There is open source panorama stitching software called Hugin, but I've never had much success with it.

Comment: Oh, I think you need to install G'MIC for GIMP and it comes with Krita by default. It's a system with hundreds of filters, and there are a few for automatic seamless texture making. It's not bad. Actually pretty amazing, it's just that Photoshop's way still seems to be more convenient and exact. I am still trying it in hope that it's only my lack of skill that gets in the way...

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Yeah I know about G'MIC and have been using it for years. Actually I was talking about GIMP's native seamless tile filter, under *Filters > Map > Tile seamless*. It works on your pattern, but it will reduce the sharpness a little, but it's not as good as a manual edit for repeating patterns like this. Better for more random textures/patterns IMHO.